# JMeter exception

Tags: jmeter

I'm getting the following exception while running the JMeter load test:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Tunnel Connection Failed"
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:487)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This isn't a whole lot of information it seems. Is there anything else about your setup you could add to the question?

Comment: I think this is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

As the output says:

> Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Tunnel Connection Failed"

JMeter is trying to access the target server through a proxy, and the connection fails for some reason.

Do you need to use a proxy? If you do, make sure the proxy is correctly configured and the target server's IP/port is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think direct connection to the target is not allowed. You may use putty to establish a tunnel.
http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/
Then connect to localhost and localport created in the putty tunnel

Answer (score 0):

Just add [HTTP Request Default](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to your Thread Group, then put your proxy details (server name or IP, PortNumber, Username, and password) as below:
[image]